# One-word synonym for "to ride roughshod over"

Tags: verbs, synonyms

I'm looking for a shorter verb with more punch. I can only think of nouns or long phrases:

- ride roughshod
- juggernaught
- ramrod
- mow down
- plough
- battering ram

What's a better way to say "to ride roughshod over"?

**EXAMPLE:** [The larger factor] bowls over / dominates / rides roughshod over [the smaller factor].

Comment: Is there a specific context? If not, this is a bit too broad.

Comment: *Plough* can also be used as a verb. In fact, depending on your context, *plough over* could work well.

Comment: Smashed through?

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close as "not a real question". Googling **define "ride roughshod over"**, the top three results are all dictionary definitions, so I don't agree "more context" is needed. Why should OP not ask which shorter verb native speakers use for this meaning?

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest [*trample*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trample).

Answer (score 3):

To [railroad](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=railroad&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=fSjLTuf4HYayhAf65rHfDQ&ved=0CBwQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4f753fccb6d01e13&biw=1137&bih=830) - *press (someone) into doing something by rushing or coercing them* has been quite popular [for about a century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=railroaded&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact context of your usage, but [Decimate](http://www.google.co.in/#q=decimate&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=687&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b) & [Trounce](http://www.google.co.in/#pq=decimate&hl=en&cp=5&gs_id=t&xhr=t&q=trounce&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=trounce&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4af2d9e6c889c72a&biw=1280&bih=687) come to mind. Also, *annihilate, obliterate, exterminate and even demolish and destroy* work well to communicate ***a decisive victory / a lopsided contest.***

To *bulldoze* someone also refers to roughshod treatment.

Answer (score 1):

M-W Unabridged defines *ride roughshod over* as

> to treat with disdain or abuse

You don't mention the context, but if you're looking for a *one-word* synonym with punch, try *[diss](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diss)*:

> **diss**, *verb*. (US, UK, slang) To put (someone) down, or show disrespect by the use of insulting language or dismissive behaviour.